# How to make the coffeescript compiler ignore part of a source file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

My use case is the following:

I decided to try coffeescript for some nodejs project and i want some of my source files to begin with `#!/usr/bin/env node`

Coffeescript treats lines that begin with `#` as comments.

I know that you can embed js code in .coffee but that is not the case because

`file.coffee`

```
`#!/usr/bin/env node`

 foo = 'bar'
```

Compiles to:
`file.js`

```
(function() {
  #!/usr/bin/env node;
  var foo;

  foo = 'bar';

}).call(this);
```

Answer (score 5):

The compiler doesn't support this.  See: https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/2215

But why not run it with `coffee` instead?

```
#!/usr/bin/env coffee
console.log 'Hello World'
```

Then just run `./my_code.coffee`. The `coffee` executable is simply a wrapper around node, and can be used instead in nearly all circumstances.

---

Or create some sort of build system that tacks it on after the compile step.  But you shouldn't really need to.

Comment: My use case for the pull request you linked was a package that installs an executable to the path. The script needs a shebang, and it needs to be Javascript (you can't expect the user to have Coffeescript installed).

Comment: So make a build script, or a cake task that calls `coffee` and compiles for you and then adds the shebang to the right file.

Comment: I did. I had to. But it's not fun if you have a folder of scripts to compile, and care about cross platform. It ought to be as easy as `coffee -o lib -c src --shebang`

Comment: Well only the file that gets executed needs the shebang, the rest do not.

Comment: Some apps install more than one executable!

Comment: Your answer is concise and informative, and i upvoted it. I was hoping that there would be some switch like the one mentioned by @ColonelPanic .Seems like i'll code a simple script that will watch for file.js changes and then prepend the shebang, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not possible with CoffeeScript, though you could - as Alex Wayne suggested - prepend the shebang manually to the file if you want to.

What I did for a project of mine, is making a very small JS script with a she-bang, that loads the JS code compiled from CoffeeScript. See this file https://github.com/meryn/jumpstart/blob/master/bin/jumpstart . This works well.

Another advantage of doing this is easier testing. You don't have to start a new child process to run the code. Instead, you can use call the `run` function, or however you have called it. This of course leaves the problem of passing proper parameters. I did this by making the `run` function (see https://github.com/meryn/jumpstart/blob/master/src/run.coffee for source) delegate practically everything to `runWith` function which can be passed all the input variables (environment, cli args, etc) the script needs.